# Static member access

Tags: c#, static-methods

It is likely that I am going about this all wrong, but I have a user control called CategoryControl, there can be many like it, for that reason I decided that many of its functions would be better served as static methods. I wanted to know if there is a "better" way of accessing these methods then passing an instance all over the class. The methods are public static as they will be updated by other methods. The though of making extension methods comes to mind..?

```
public CategoryControl(UserCategory userCategory)
{
   InitializeComponent();

   PopulateControl(userCategory, this);
}

private static void PopulateControl(UserCategory userCategory, CategoryControl instance)
{

   SetCategoryTitle(userCategory, instance);

   SetPercentCorrect(userCategory, instance);

   SetQuestionsMissed(userCategory, instance);

   SetBackgroundBar(userCategory, instance);

   SetForegroundBar(userCategory, instance);

}
```

**Updated::**

The longer story is that I have a Panel on the screen, the panel contains relevant user categories. By relevant I mean that the user has the option of changing courses thus displaying a new set of categories. A user can also change the values of a category based on their interaction with the software. So...

A panel shows the categories of a course.

I maintain a list of the active Category Controls in the panel, and the main form tells the panel when to draw a new set of categories.

```
public void InitializeProgressPanel(UserCategories parentCategories)
{
   Contract.Requires(parentCategories != null, "parentCategories is null.");

   RemoveAllControlsFromList(_categoryControls);

   UserCategories sortedUserCategories = parentCategories.SortByWorst();

   int categoriesCount = parentCategories.Count();

   int spacer = (Height - (CategoryControl.Controls_Height * categoriesCount)) / categoriesCount+1;

   for (int i = 0; i < sortedUserCategories.Count; i++)
   {
      CategoryControl cc = new CategoryControl((UserCategory)sortedUserCategories[i]);

      cc.Left = 0;

      if (i == 0)
         cc.Top = spacer;
      else
         cc.Top = (Controls[i - 1].Bottom + spacer);

      Controls.Add(cc);
      _categoryControls.Add(cc);

      }
}
```

Comment: why do you think this method should be static?

Comment: @BrokenGlass: Woops, just flagged your post instead of upvoting, can that be undone?!

Comment: "there can be many like it, for that reason I decided that many of its functions would be better served as static methods"  That is not at all the reason to have static methods.   Instance methods can also share behavior -- all instances share the same instance methods...

Comment: @psycho, I don't think it can be undone, but since nobody else will flag BrokenGlass' comment, it just means that your flag weight will go down.

Comment: I don't see the advantages to using a static method here.

Comment: @Kirk Say that last part again, all instances share the same methods? So if I instead make these private void methods, they are all shared implicitly rather then each instance having their own?

Comment: @Siegeon -- that is not how instance methods work.  Instance methods do not require more resources per instance (unlike fields).

Comment: @Kirk: thanks, couldn't find or understand informations about this in FAQ!

Comment: Must have missed that in my reading, thank you that saves a lot of the head ache.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would certainly not make extension methods if I had a class in hand that I could extend. Remember, the purpose of extension methods is to extend types that you *cannot* extend yourself.

The question at hand then is, should you say:

```
class C 
{
    public void Foo() { ... }
}
```

or

```
class C
{
    public static void Foo(C c) { ... }
}
```

I would ask some questions like:

- Is the class ever going to be subclassed? If so, should this be a virtual method?
- Is Foo the kind of thing that an instance does to itself, or the sort of thing that it has done to it? An animal *eats* on its own, but an animal *is fed* by someone else.

UPDATE:

Some more questions I'd ask myself:

- Are the properties and whatnot you are setting ever going to change? The less mutability you have in a class, the easier it is to test, the easier it is to reason about, and the fewer bugs you'll have. If the properties and whatnot are never going to change then do not set them in *any* kind of method. Set them in the constructor and then never worry about them again; they're correct.

Comment: This class will "never" be sub-classed, this class draws specific information from user Categories after some very light formatting. Each of the individual methods when called will redraw their specific portion with the updated information. This is more or less a presentation class.

Comment: The controls are the values of the class User Category (with some light formatting). The individual values are changed through user interaction, and need to be updated when that happens. Furthermore the specific userCategory can go away. I have courses, and courses have user categories, so if the user changes the course the whole group of categories goes away and new ones are needed for the new course. (See above for further code example)

Comment: @Siegeon: Based on what you've said so far, I see absolutely no reason why you'd want to make these static methods.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make them instance members, and do it like this

```
private UserCategory _userCategory;

public CategoryControl(UserCategory userCategory)
{
   InitializeComponent();

   this._userCategory = userCategory;
   this.PopulateControl();
}

private void PopulateControl()
{
   // to see userCategory you'd do "this._userCategory"
   // to see the specific instance you could simply do "this"

   SetCategoryTitle();

   SetPercentCorrect();

   SetQuestionsMissed();

   SetBackgroundBar();

   SetForegroundBar();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems better to have the functionality on one of the two classes involved in the interaction, rather than on some third party.

Here are two ways that spring to mind:

1. CategoryControl could have a public function PopulateCategory(UserCategory userCat)
2. UserCategory could have a public function PopulateFromControl(CategoryControl ctrl)

If all those operations about title and percent etc need to be separate actions, you'd just follow the model above but have separate functions for each item.

Answer (score 1):

Just a shot in the dark here, but I'd probably try for something more like this:

```
private void PopulateControl(UserCategory userCategory)
{
    CategoryTitle = GetCategoryTitle(userCategory);
    PercentCorrect = GetPercentCorrect(userCategory);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some questions may help...(?)

- What benefit do you perceive in making the methods static? Converting the method to static, you are taking away the implicit passing of "this", and passing it in manually every time. How does that help? (It won't make the code any more efficient, it just means you have to pass 'instance' into every call you make, so you need to write more code)
- Does the user category change a lot? If not, rather than passing it in for every call, would it make more sense to make it a member variable?
- Would you really want to call all these static methods one by one to change all the different parameters of the control? Look at how the client will *use* this class and you may find that you can roll all of those options into one or two methods that take a bunch of parameters and apply them all in one hit. (Often if you want to change one setting, you will want to change several settings together)

Comment: 1. I was unclear if there was a benefit to making the methods static.
2. User Category changes often, but infrequently it seemed better to updated the individual portions of the control as needed, rather then one super update.
3. On second thought it may be better to update them all, the issue is that there are a ton of controls, each showing a different category. I was worried about calling to many updates, and slowing the whole program.

Comment: @Siegson: Thinking about performance: good. Making design decisions on the basis of speculations about performance in advance of having data: very bad. If you are worried about performance then *set a performance goal*, *write a performance test*, and *see whether you met your goal or not*. Don't be making design decisions on the basis of hunches.